# Rails how to test Resque in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I have **resque** and **resque-scheduler** running on my local machine.

Can I test whether my jobs is working or by copy and paste following code in ***rails console***?

```
Resque.enqueue_in 3.seconds, SnippetHighlighter
```

this is my **SnippetHighlighter.rb** code

```
def self.perform
  puts "it works
end
```

anyone has same experience? thanks

Comment: Yes, I think you can, remember running redis-server in your localhost since resque works with redis

Comment: I run above code but nothing shows on terminal log, how do I know something happen?

Comment: You can set a debug breakpoint inside func `perform`, btw are you running `rake resque:work`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `/config/environments/development.rb` has `resque` as queue adapter instead of `inline`:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :resque
```

Open one terminal and start resque:

```
VERBOSE=1 QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
```

Open a second terminal and start scheduler:

```
VERBOSE=1 rake resque:scheduler
```